# PHP Checkboxes checked by default | How do you only check 2 checkboxes and leave the rest unchecked in foreach statement

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, checkbox, foreach

I am working with a Wordpress theme for Real Estate.
I'm tweaking the code for a filter search which contains 4 checkboxes under "Action" - namely, "Sales"; "Rentals"; "Foreclosure" and "Other". Then there are several checkboxes for "Categories", such as, "House"; "Apartment", "Duplex" etc...

An "Action" checkbox would need to be selcted together with a "Category" checkbox for it to render data on a Google map relative to the search criteria.
The trouble is, All of these checkboxes are checked by default.

What I would like to accomplish for the purpose of this excercise is 2 fold: 
 1. To have two checkboxes checked in "Action" ($tax_terms) and two checkboxes checked in "Category" ($categories)
 2. The action and category checkboxes are set out in alphabetical order (By default) such as (Foreclosure, Other, Rentals, Sales). I would need to set a custom order such as (Sales, Rentals, Foreclosure, Other)

Here is the first bit of code defining the variables:

```
<?php
$icons          =   array();
$taxonomy       =   'property_action_category';
$tax_terms      =   get_terms($taxonomy);
$taxonomy_cat   =   'property_category';
$categories     =   get_terms($taxonomy_cat);


// add only actions
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
    $icon_name              =   'wp_estate_icon'.$tax_term->slug;
    $icons[$tax_term->slug] =   esc_html( get_option($icon_name) );  
}

// add only categories
foreach ($categories as $categ) {
    $icon_name              =   'wp_estate_icon'.$categ->slug;
    $icons[$categ->slug]    =   esc_html( get_option($icon_name) );  
}
?>
```

Here are the filters:

```
<?php
   ////////////////////////// enable /disable map filters
   $show_filter_map_status  =  esc_html ( get_option('wp_estate_show_filter_map','') );
   $home_small_map_status   =  esc_html ( get_option('wp_estate_home_small_map','') );
   if($show_filter_map_status!='no'){
   ?>

   <div class="gmap-menu-wrapper" >   
        <div class="gmap-menu" id="gmap-menu" <?php if (!is_front_page() ||  (is_front_page() && $home_small_map_status=='yes') ) print 'style="display:none;"'; ?> >
            <div id="closefilters"></div>
            <div class="action_filter" >
                <?php

                foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
                        print '<div class="checker"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"  name="filter_action[]" id="'.$tax_term->slug.'" class="'.$tax_term->slug.'"  value="'.$tax_term->name.'"/><label for="'.$tax_term->slug.'"><span></span>';
                        if( $icons[$tax_term->slug]!='' ){
                             print '<img src="'.$icons[$tax_term->slug].'" alt="'.$tax_term->name.'">' . $tax_term->name . '</label></div>';
                        }else{
                             print '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/css/css-images/'.$tax_term->slug.'icon.png" alt="'.$tax_term->name.'">' . $tax_term->name . '</label></div>';
                        }
                }
                ?>
            </div>

            <div class="type-filters">
                <?php
                foreach ($categories as $categ) {
                     print '<div class="checker"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"  name="filter_type[]" id="'.$categ->slug.'"  class="' . $categ->slug . '" value="' . $categ->name . '"/><label for="' . $categ->slug. '"><span></span>';
                     if( $icons[$categ->slug]!='' ){
                         print' <img src="'.$icons[$categ->slug].'" alt="'.$categ->slug.'">' . $categ->name . '</label></div>';
                     }else{
                         print' <img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/css/css-images/'.$categ->slug.'icon.png" alt="'.$categ->name.'">' . $categ->name . '</label></div>';
                     }                      
                }
                ?>
```

I've done some research, and the best suggestion was to add an index to the foreach loop and do something like '.($index == 0 ? ' checked="checked"' : '').'

The trouble is, I have now idea how to implement this as I kept receiving Syntax errors.

Any and all help would be sincerely appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Kyle

Comment: Use attribute `checked`. For older browsers `checked="checked"`

Comment: I am currently using that attribute, I cannot figure out where to place the array to specify which checkboxes should be checked and which should not